# how to I replace numeric values with a string in an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to replace all numeric values in a column in my data frame with a string value. The following doesn't seem to work.

```
df <- within(df, myCol[is.numeric(myCol)] <- 'NOTMISSING')
```

Even though the df has some values as NA and others as numbers, all values are being replaced with NOTMISSING.

Also tried

```
df <- within(df, myCol[is_numeric(myCol)] <- 'NOTMISSING')
```

Any pointers highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a dummy dataframe that you can provide?

Comment: `df[is.numeric(df)]="string"`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `is.numeric`:

> The default method for is.numeric returns TRUE if its argument is of mode "numeric" (type > "double" or type "integer") and not a factor, and FALSE otherwise.

So for a vector, `is.numeric` returns a single `TRUE`, it doesn't test each element as you might expect.

```
is.numeric(c(5, 4, 3))
[1] TRUE

is.numeric(c(5, 4, NA))
[1] TRUE
```

That's why either all or none of the values are changed to NOTMISSING.

@eg-r's fix is correct.  Here's a [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) way to accomplish the same.

```
> df<-tibble(myCol=c(5, 4, NA))
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  myCol
  <dbl>
1     5
2     4
3    NA
> df %>% mutate(myCol = ifelse(is.na(myCol), myCol, "NOTMISSING"))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
       myCol
       <chr>
1 NOTMISSING
2 NOTMISSING
3       <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

NAs can be numeric (especially if the other values in that column are all numeric). Try this :

```
df$myCol = ifelse(is.numeric(df$myCol) & !is.na(df$myCol), "NOTMISSING", df$myCol)
```

Or if all you want to do is turn all values in that column that are not NA as that string, you can change your original code to :

```
df <- within(df, myCol[!is.na(myCol)] <- 'NOTMISSING')
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to replace the values in the whole dataframe:

```
df[!is.na(df)] <- 'NOTMISSING'
```

I wanted to make this as a comment to the answer by [@eg-r](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/38628/140204), but I do not have enough reputation.